# Django Error that does nothing?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

My project in django 2.0, python 3.x  and I think its when i go into django admin I get this series of trackbacks and red letters that I assume is some kind of error, i just have no idea whatsoever what it is.

ERROR does nothing:ERROR does nothing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in
_write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b) ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host [30/May/2018 14:06:28] "GET /static/admin/css/changelists.css HTTP/1.1" 500 59
---------------------------------------- Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 61210) [30/May/2018 14:06:28] "GET /static/admin/js/jquery.init.js HTTP/1.1" 200 363 Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in
_write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b) ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()   File "C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\Django_projects\Pycharm\Interpretes\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 86, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9' TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 639, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()   File "C:\Users\Andre\Desktop\Django_projects\Pycharm\Interpretes\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 154, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()   File "C:\Users\Andre\Anaconda3\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

It apparently does nothing but scare the hell out of me, if anyone has any thoughts please enlighten me.
I think it may or may not stop the server from running but i am not sure as I run it in a ec2 instance from AWS and in my IDE pycharm the console gets full of this.

Answer (score 2):

You have an environment variable named `SERVER_PROTOCOL` that is not set.

Try giving it a value such as `HTTP/0.9`.

This will only fix this error. Not sure if there are other errors as well.

Setting environment variables in Windows PowerShell:

```
setx SERVER_PROTOCOL "HTTP/0.9"
```

And restart and command prompt.